# How to make navigation bar and status bar looks like a white scrim?

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

In my theme, I set

```
<style name="AppTheme">
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#1affffff</item>
  <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
  ....
</style>
```

But if I set `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` to true, the white color won't be shown, it would be a grey scrim. What I expect is the content can be shown behind navigationbar, statusbar and toolbar, but with a white scrim over these xxxxxbar, how can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

it is like this because your action bar is not over your layout but it is over window background add this line to your current style:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```